# Separate email for specific validation

Tags: validation, email, filter, yii2

Is there a way to separate the values of an email variable? I been searching topics about that and I can't seem to find any. I'm using yii2 and I want the Sign Up page to only accept specific emails. For example, the user would sign up and it would only accept Yahoo emails with @yahoo.com suffixes. It would not accept any other email other than yahoo emails.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to use `match` validator.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // ...
        ['email', 'match', 'pattern' => '/@yahoo\.com$/i', 'message' => 'Only emails from yahoo.com domain are allowed.']
    ];
}
```

Regex pattern means

> match everything ending (`$` character) with `@yahoo.com` no matter the letter case (`i` flag)